# Trying to understand ISO image in context of VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have created a CentOS VM on VirtualBox. I have used an ISO image to boot it.
Now, in the CentOS VM image, there is an option to install to hard drive. I chose that option, went through all the installation steps. But even after that, in the settings window for the VM, the IDE controller is shown as the iso image wit the same location of the iso file.
Is this how an installation using ISO image supposed to behave?

I am confused because, when I use live CD or DVD to install a VM, I can then remove the DVD or CD and the VM still works. But here it seems that I am always dependent on the iso image being perpetually present in my machine. Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storage page of the settings window for the VM you are shown all the IDE and SATA controllers that exist in the virtual machine. By default VirtualBox seems to create virtual IDE optical drives and virtual SATA hard drives (you can change that, but you probably don't need to).

I suspect that what you are seeing is that the Centos ISO file image is still associated with the virtual optical drive. That just means that when you start the VM Centos will think that the CD is still inserted in the drive. You can "eject" the CD from the "Devices" menu of the VM by selecting "CD/DVD Devices" and "Remove disk from virtual drive".

You probably want to install the VirtualBox guest additions, though. When you do that VirtualBox will replace the Centos virtual CD with the guest additions virtual CD.